# Timeout after [5000] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation; while deploying the EAR in JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I have used the below `persistence.xml` for my application:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="DELIVERYCENTER">
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   <!--jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/deliverycenter</jta-data-source-->
   <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/deliverycenter</non-jta-data-source>
   <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
   </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

But, it's giving me:

> JBAS013413: Timeout after [5000] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation. Process must be restarted. Step that first updated the service container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "delctr.ear")]'

Could somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I've used these settings which increased timeout and it helped me:
-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=6000